# To use subclasses only for semmantical purposes?

Tags: java, class

I have seen sometimes the use of subclasses only for semantical purposes, and I was wondering about pros and cons of doing it, and if it should be consdierated a good practice or not.

For example:

#### With semantical subclasses

List of classes:

-`abstract class V3` (it is a vector with attributes x, y and z, and some manipulation methods)

-`class Lengths extends V3` (it just extends V3 and do not add new methods or attributes)

-`class Point extends V3` (just extends V3)

This way, some methods, like `void setCuboidLengths(Lenghts l)` will accept only Lengths classes as argument, and others, like `Point getCuboidCenter()` will return a Point object.

#### Without semantical subclases.

Only one class:

-`class V3`

Instead of using more specific classes, we use the generic V3: `void setCuboidLenghts(V3 v)`, `V3 getCuboidCenter()`.

Comment: It sounds like composition would be more appropriate: `Lengths` and `Point` should *have* `V3` instance(s), but not *be* `V3` instances.

Comment: Does [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/405579/1352) asked yesterday on [SoftwareEngineering.se] answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantic classes make it harder to misunderstand the interface of a function and by extension harder to make mistakes. 
As Andy Turner said, I would make the V3 a member of the Point and Lenght classes instead of inheriting from it, unless you have a reason not to.
The disadvantage width semantic classes are the number of classes and explicit conversions you have to do can be a lot, but a few well made semantic classes can save hours of headaches.

Edit:
[The post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405579/whats-the-name-of-the-technique-of-using-very-specific-types-to-help-catch-erro) Jörg W Mittag linked has some good documents for reading up on this pattern. Please check them out.